# Pygame - number of sprites in a group

Tags: python, pygame

How do I determine how many sprites are in a group? len() *should* work, but just... doesn't.
Code:

```
print(len(sprites))
print('sprites',sprites)
```

Output:

```
0
('sprites', <Group(1 sprites)>)
```

(Yes, I did make a group called 'sprites')

EDIT:
I renamed "sprites" to "aliveSprites", just in case that was the issue. No luck. 
Here's the code:

```
print(len(aliveSprites.sprites()))
if len(aliveSprites.sprites()) == 0:
    thing = test()
    aliveSprites.add(thing)

    thing.rect.x = 100
    thing.rect.y = 300

print('sprites',aliveSprites)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (as ugly as it looks)

```
len(sprites.sprites)
```

Pygame Sprites Group does support the len operation.

```
pygame.sprite.Group
```

A simple container for Sprite objects. This class can be inherited to create containers with more specific behaviors. The constructor takes any number of Sprite arguments to add to the Group. The group supports the following standard Python operations:

```
in      test if a Sprite is contained
len     the number of Sprites contained
bool    test if any Sprites are contained
iter    iterate through all the Sprites
```

Comment: weirdly enough, .sprites gives me a "TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()" but .sprites() has no effect on the output...

Comment: I would recommend changing your group name and trying that as a first action. If that still does not work, you could always try something less recommended such as len(sprites[1]) considering the group is a name and a list of sprites.

Comment: I tried changing the name - see edit on original post - with no luck. Apparently - I just tried this - [1] or [0] or whatever (indexing, I guess it's called) doesn't work on groups and generates an error. Also, I checked - as soon as I use .sprites() on the group it's messed up, (always has 0 items, regardless of original content.) so [1] just produces a "list index out of range" error... I'm not sure what to make of this. (I'm new to pygame)

Comment: Wait! I just figured out what it was. Nevermind. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

You need to call [sprites()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.sprites) to get the list of sprites

```
print(len(sprites.sprites()))
```