# If statement to check if sprite.Group = 0

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame, grouping, sprite

I trying to create game using pygame,then using myTarget=pygame.sprite.Group()
My problem is how to create if statement that tell if myTarget=0,
I already using

```
if myTarget=="0"
```

and

```
if myTarget == [0]
```

But none of that code triggered, I also already checked that inside that group no more sprites (using print(myTarget) that says <Group(0 sprites)>
Sorry for my English

Comment: Welcome Feritell, does your code raise an exception? if so, please edit your question and include the full traceback. Also, did you notice you are missing `:` in `if myTarget == "0":` ?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084366/pygame-number-of-sprites-in-a-group

Comment: What meaning do you give to comparing with zero? Are you trying to check if the group is empty?

Comment: The only thing that's equal to `"0"` is the string `"0"`.  The only thing that is equal to `[0]` is a list containing a single zero.  Your `Group` is obviously neither of these things, you need to use the documented methods or attributes of the `Group` class to determine the number of sprites it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `SpriteGroup` object is *not* able to be directly indexed.

You can use the `SpriteGroup.sprites()` member function, which returns a python list of all the elements and then just tested item `0` in that list:

```
import pygame

class SimpleSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface( ( 64, 64 ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        self.image.fill( ( 255, 255, 12 ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


pygame.init()

sprite_group = pygame.sprite.Group()  # empty group

# Make and add 3 sprites to the group
sprite_a = SimpleSprite()
sprite_b = SimpleSprite()
sprite_c = SimpleSprite()
sprite_group.add( sprite_a )
sprite_group.add( sprite_b )
sprite_group.add( sprite_c )

print( "Group has %d sprites" % ( len( sprite_group ) ) )

if ( sprite_a == sprite_group.sprites()[0] ):                 # <<-- HERE
    print( "Sprite A is the 0th item in the group" )
else:
    print( "Sprite A is NOT the 0th item" )
```

Which gives me the output:

> ...
> Group has 3 sprites 
> Sprite A is the 0th item in the group

Also you can use the `len()` function on a Sprite Group to test if it is empty.